# Laravel : command php artisan route:list generates an error : AuthController not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working in a laravel project running version 5.6.39. When I try to run a command **php artisan route:list**, it generates an error saying "`ReflectionException : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist`".

routes\web.php looks like...
[image]

How can I resolve this issue? Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload` then rerun the artisan command.

Comment: It didn't work. shows the same problem.

Comment: Check the namespace in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` and make sure it matches.

Comment: There is no any controller named AuthController in the directory you specified.

Comment: Then why did you mention in the web.php file if the AuthController doesn't exists?

Comment: That's your problem, you either need to A) create `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` or B) if it exists in a different directory, move it and update the namespace so your routes can correctly reach it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I accidentally deleted AuthController.php file from Auth directory. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this issue is when you run `php artisan route:list` laravel reads all routes from `routes` folder and executes every controller that exists in them and if laravel couldn't find the controller or there is an error in them laravel throws an exception

so with that in mind it means you either removed `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` or you moved it to another folder but didn't update the `AuthController` namespace and also the namespace in `web.php` so in your case you need to fix namespace in `web.php` and also in controller until they match

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I accidentally deleted AuthController.php file from Auth directory. Now it is working.